# angular ui router passing just the data from $http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

```
resolve: {
  document: function ($stateParams, specialGet, $http) {
    var id = $stateParams.id      
    return specialGet(id)
  },
},

.factory('specialGet', function (Pusher, $q, $http) {
  return function (id) {
    return 
      $http.get('/api/document/'+id)
  }
})
```

When I inject document into my controller I get an object with these properties

```
config: Object
data: Object
headers: function (name) {
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

How do I pass just the data into document instead of the return being this object and having to get the data afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue on the http promise using the then method, and return the desired data there.

```
resolve: {
  document: function ($stateParams, $http) {
    var nid = $stateParams.id      
    return $http.get('/api/document/'+id).then(function(response) { return response.data; });
  },
},
```